# lock conversion update locks

Tags: database, transactions, locking

I am reading chapter 6 of your book, Principles of Transaction Processing and the concept of update lock explained in there is not very clear to me. Basically, what I am not clear about is that won't locking conversion deadlock occur when you try to upgrade a update lock to the write lock. Say we say the deadlock does not occur during conversion of update lock to write lock. Can you then not have the following scenario

u1[x]r2[x]w1[x]w1[z]w2[z].

u1[x] means transaction 1 has a update lock on x.

So in the above history transaction 2 is before 1 on x but after 1 on z. Doesnt that violate serializability?

I would really appreciate if you can clear this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Oh nvm, I just read that the book says that you cant upgrade from an update lock to a write lock if you have concurrent read operations. So yeah it won't violate serializability that way :). Also if anyone happens to stumble across this, you can't upgrade a read lock to an update lock because that would essentially cause deadlocks due to lock conversion too.